# Get entity projection by type and name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I need to use a custom rest controller, but I would like to pass the projection to use as a paramater, just the way it works with spring data rest.

Right now, I know how to create a projection using the projectionFactory when I want to use a specific projection:

```
projectionFactory.createProjection(IPaymentMethodConfig.class, pm)
```

Is there a way to retrieve the projection using the name and type in the projection definition? For example, here is the projection definition:

```
@Projection(name = "list", types = {PaymentMethod.class})
```

I would like to create the same projection as above, but using some code like this instead:

```
projectionFactory.createProjection(projName, PaymentMethod.class, myObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the [`PersistentEntityProjector`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/support/PersistentEntityProjector.java). Then just use the `Object project(Object source)` method. The projection definitions should be retrievable from the `RepositoryRestConfiguration` through the `getProjectionConfiguration()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel already summarized it, so I'm going to show the relevant code.

Inject a bean of type `RepositoryRestConfiguration` in your class:

```java
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;

...

private final RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration;

...
```

Then call `getProjectionConfiguration().getProjectionType(...)` with the required source type and projection name.

```java
private Class<?> getProjectionType(Class<?> sourceType, String projection) {
    return repositoryRestConfiguration.getProjectionConfiguration().getProjectionType(sourceType, projection);
}
```

Hence in your example:

```java
Class<?> projectionType = getProjectionType(PaymentMethod.class, projName);
```